# Call javascript code from python?

Tags: javascript, python-2.7, openerp-7

i have a problem with a button in a popup window, i want that this button open a new popup window without closing the current popup window, but this button close the current popup window. this is my python code:

```
 def button_article(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
  ctx = (context or {}).copy()
  ctx['article'] = self.browse(cr, uid, ids[0], context=context).product_id.id
  ctx['form_view_ref'] = 'itk_entrepot.itk_entrepot_article_maj'
  if ctx['article'] :
      return {
    'name':'Article',
    'view_type':'form',
    'view_mode':'form',
    'res_model':'product.product',
    'view_id':False,
    'target':'new',
    'type':'ir.actions.act_window',
    'domain':[('id','=',ctx['article'])],
    'context':ctx,
    'nodestroy':True,
    'res_id':ctx['article'],
        }
  else : return True
```

i asked for a solution but i don't have any answer so i decide to call javascript code from python. anyone have idea about How to call javascript code from python in openerp ?

Comment: Python runs on the server side, while you want to run JavaScript on the client side. You can't call client-side JavaScript directly from Python, you have to include it as a script on the page.

Comment: Hi jgillich, thank you for your answer, do you have an example ?